# linear program solver with box/bound constraints?

Tags: r, optimization

Is there a linear program optimizer in R that supports upper and lower bound constraints?

The libraries [limSolve](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/limSolve/index.html) and [lpSolve](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lpSolve/index.html) do not support bound constraints.

It is not at all clear from the [R Cran Optimization Task View](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html) page which LP optimizers support bound constraints.

Comment: Certainly, all lp solvers will, including lpSolve.  Instead of, say, $a \leq x \leq b$, just make $x \geq a$ and $x \leq b$ as two constraints in the constraint matrix for lpSolve.

Or am I failing to understand your question?

Comment: +1 This is a clever approach, however, the memory required to store the constraint matrices explodes.

Comment: Are you familiar with AMPL?  There's an R interface to the GLPK, which has an AMPL-like language for describing the problem.  I haven't used it myself, though.  [R link](http://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/rglp/) and [GLPK](http://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/).

Comment: "the memory required to store the constraint matrices explodes". No, it doesn't: it grows as 2*k (k is the number of parameters.)

Comment: limSolve support bound constraints. You may even use package LIM (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/LIM/) to formulate those in human readable format. For example: 'Faeces = [minFaeces,maxFaeces]'.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that all linear programming solvers assume their variables are positive. If you need different lower bounds, the easiest thing is to perform a linear transformation on the variables, apply lpSolve (or Rglpk), and retransform the variables. This has been explained in a posting to R-help some time ago -- which I am not able to find at the moment.

By the way, Rglpk has a parameter 'bounds' that allows to define upper and lower bounds through vectors, not matrices. That may attenuate your concern about matrices growing too fast.

Answer (score 0):

Commands in the [Rglpk](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rglpk/Rglpk.pdf) package do constraints.

Or consider the General Purpose Continuous Solvers;

- *Package stats offers several general purpose optimization routines. First, function optim() provides an implementation of the Broyden-Fletcher-Goldfarb-Shanno (BFGS) method, bounded BFGS, conjugate gradient, Nelder-Mead, and simulated annealing (SANN) optimization methods. It utilizes gradients, if provided, for faster convergence. Typically it is used for unconstrained optimization but includes an option for box-constrained optimization.*
- *Additionally, for minimizing a function subject to linear inequality constraints stats contains the routine constrOptim().*
- *nlminb() offers unconstrained and constrained optimization using PORT routines.*